# Opera userscript for event "load" doesn't always work

Tags: javascript, opera, userscripts

I have the following user javascript in opera:

```
window.addEventListener( 
  'load', 
  function (e) { 
    document.title += " [MY loaded]"; 
 }, false);
```

I just want to change the title after it finishes loading the page, so that I know it's done. The title will be monitored by another script. My problem is that some pages finish loading but the title is not changed, and I have no idea why or how to fix it. Example:

https://docs.google.com/a/dirus.org/spreadsheet/viewform

Which gives me a "page not found" but the script apparently isn't triggered.

EDIT: The code received by the browser apparently is not related to the problem, as the title gets correctly modified when loading the following page, that gives me a 404:

http://50-118-237-24.gci.net/webscr.uk/page.html

Comment: If the page isn't found, your page isn't loaded, which means the script isn't included...why would it be?

Comment: Because the "page not found" page is loaded. But assuming it won't trigger the "load" event if the browser get a non-200 response (which I'm assuming it's the case), what other event can I listen to be able to change the title when the browser finishes loading the whatever-error-happened page?

Comment: Wait, maybe I'm misunderstanding. What's a "userscript"? I don't think I saw that when I read your question. Sorry if it's obvious. But maybe that's what's confusing me

Comment: Basically, it's javascript placed in a specific folder of Opera that Opera will run automatically for me. I'm somewhat experienced in javascript, but new to this userscript thing (the browser running it for me)... it seems simple, but I admit I might have a misconception of it. That's the understanding I have of it so far.

Comment: Ahh I see, that's my problem :) Like I said, I missed that part about it being a "userscript", so I thought it was just JavaScript on a page...and you were asking why your JavaScript wasn't running when the page wasn't found...I was confused why there was confusion :) I see though. I'll have to look into that, because I know nothing about userscripts. Hopefully someone else knows why it wouldn't always execute!

Comment: So let me just make sure I understand. You have this userscript that should be executing on every page, because it's setup to do that. Your script simply changes the `document.title` when the `window` "load" event occurs. But you've found that your script doesn't execute on all pages, for some reason. The examples you've provided always return a 404...is it consistently not executing for **only** 404 responses? Or is it not even consistent with those pages? Did you try adding other code (like a simple `alert("hi");`) not in an event handler or anything?

Comment: Right. Thanks anyway Ian. :) It's my first userscript, so I can't say I know much about it either. I'm praying to Mímir that someone knows why...

Comment: My second example, after I edited the question, is a 404 where the title is changed. So, no, it's not consistently not executing for all 404s. I haven't tried the alert, I'll check.

Comment: I added the alert and it didn't run for that page, so I got suspicious about it being HTTPS. A quick search led me to the answer... thanks @Ian

Comment: Cool, glad you got it figured out! Sorry I was confused and didn't realize the differences in the tests you had. I wouldn't have even thought about HTTPS, nice find :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that userscripts don't run by default on HTTPS pages. According to Opera documentation at http://www.opera.com/docs/userjs/using/ :

> User JavaScript will not be loaded on pages accessed using the opera:
>   protocol. By default, it is also not loaded on pages accessed using
>   the HTTPS: protocol.

The solution to the problem is a bit further below in the documentation:

> If you want to run User JavaScripts on these pages, you will need to
>   enable the User Javascript on HTTPS setting in opera:config.

Thanks Ian for the support. :)